# OpenGL, glMapNamedBuffer takes a long time

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, gpgpu, compute-shader

I've been writing an openGL program that generates vertices on the GPU using compute shaders, the problem is I need to read back the number of vertices from a buffer written to by one compute shader dispatch on the CPU so that I can allocate a buffer of the right size for the next compute shader dispatch to fill with vertices.

```
/*
* Stage 1- Populate the 3d texture with voxel values
*/
_EvaluateVoxels.Use();
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
GLPrintErrors("glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);");
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, _RandomSeedTexture);
glBindImageTexture(2, _VoxelValuesTexture, 0, GL_TRUE, NULL, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_R32F);
_EvaluateVoxels.SetVec3("CellSize", voxelCubeDims);
SetMetaBalls(metaballs);
_EvaluateVoxels.SetVec3("StartPos", chunkPosLL);
glDispatchCompute(voxelDim.x + 1, voxelDim.y + 1, voxelDim.z + 1);
glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_IMAGE_ACCESS_BARRIER_BIT);
/*
* Stage 2 - Calculate the marching cube's case for each cube of 8 voxels,
* listing those that contain polygons and counting the no of vertices that will be produced
*/
_GetNonEmptyVoxels.Use();
_GetNonEmptyVoxels.SetFloat("IsoLevel", isoValue);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 3, _IntermediateDataSSBO);
glBindBufferBase(GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BUFFER, 0, _AtomicCountersBuffer);
glDispatchCompute(voxelDim.x, voxelDim.y, voxelDim.z);
glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT | GL_ATOMIC_COUNTER_BARRIER_BIT);
//printStage2(_IntermediateDataSSBO, true);
_StopWatch.StopTimer("stage2");
_StopWatch.StartTimer("getvertexcounter");


// this line takes a long time
unsigned int* vals = (unsigned int*)glMapNamedBuffer(_AtomicCountersBuffer, GL_READ_WRITE);
unsigned int vertex_counter = vals[1];
unsigned int index_counter = vals[0];
vals[0] = 0;
vals[1] = 0;
glUnmapNamedBuffer(_AtomicCountersBuffer);
```

The image below shows times in milliseconds that each stage of the code takes to run, "timer Evaluate" refers to the method as a whole, IE the sum total of the previous stages. getvertexcounter refers to only the mapping, reading and unmapping of a buffer containing the number of vertices. Please see code for more detail.

[image]

I've found this to be by far the slowest stage in the process, and I gather it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of the communication between openGL and the GPU and the need to synchronise data that was written by the compute shader so it can be read by the CPU. My question is this: Is this delay avoidable? I don't think that the overall approach is flawed because I know that someone else has implemented the algorithm in a similar way, albeit using direct X (I think).

You can find my code at https://github.com/JimMarshall35/Marching-cubes-cpp/tree/main/MarchingCubes , the code in question is in the file ComputeShaderMarcher.cpp and the method `unsigned int ComputeShaderMarcher::GenerateMesh(const glm::vec3& chunkPosLL, const glm::vec3& chunkDim, const glm::ivec3& voxelDim, float isoValue, GLuint VBO)`

Comment: Are you sure that the mapping itself is the problem? I guess this is the first operation you perform after the compute shader invocation that really depends on the compute shader, so it might very well be that the compute shader takes that long and you only notice it when you hit the first blocking method. Try to use a real profile (NSight or whatever), profiling OpenGL function calls with a timer is not going to give you meaningful results.

Comment: Regarding the question itself: You have to present all relevant information to reproduce/identify the problem in the question itself. Linking to a github repository is possible as additional data, but the important code has to be in the question itself.

Comment: "it might very well be that the compute shader takes that long and you only notice it when you hit the first blocking method"- this thought did cross my mind - perhaps this is the case. I've never heard of NSight before - after a quick google it looks great, I'll have to get hold of it. I'll see what I'll see what i can do with the question itself - but i fear it may take a lot of code to reproduce/identify the problem in the question itself and so thought it'd be better to just link the github repo and say what file it's in

Comment: The goal here is to create a repository of questions and answers. Providing important information as links is problematic when the linked target changes or gets deleted. That's why all questions on SO have to be self contained.

Comment: Yeh that's fair enough - I'll edit my question to make it conform to this, but tomorrow as i'm going to bed now

Answer (score 1):

In order to access data from a buffer that you have had OpenGL write some data to, the CPU must halt execution until the GPU has actually *written* that data. Whatever process you use to access this data (`glMapBufferRange`, `glGetBufferSubData`, etc), that process must halt until the GPU has finished generating the data.

So don't try to access GPU-generated data until you're sure the GPU has actually generated it (or you have absolutely nothing better to do on the CPU than wait). Use [fence sync objects](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sync_Object#Fence) to test whether the GPU has finished executing past a certain point.